# Type '[]' is missing the following properties from type ''" graphql

Tags: node.js, typeorm, typegraphql

I have a simple Resolver in **typeGraphQL** which **findOne** and returns a record against the query,i have a similar implementation for **Company** model that works just fine, but the **Product** doesnot work, let me show you my code

**entity/Product.ts**

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BaseEntity } from "typeorm";
import { ObjectType, Field, ID } from "type-graphql";

//the field decorator represents which fields user can query

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Product extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() 
  id: number;

  @Field({nullable: true})
  @Column({length: 300, nullable: true})
  description: string;

  @Field({nullable: true})
  @Column({length: 300, nullable: true})
  image: string;

  @Field({nullable: true})
  @Column({ length: 300, nullable: true })
  stock: string;

  @Field({nullable: true})
  @Column({ length: 300, nullable: true })
  color: string;

  @Field()
  @Column({length: 300})
  name: string;

  @Field()
  @Column({length: 300})
  company_id: string;
}
```

**Resolver**

```
import { Resolver, Query,Arg } from "type-graphql";
import { Product } from "../../entity/Product";


@Resolver()
export class ProductResolver {

  @Query(() => Product)
  async companyProducts(
    @Arg("name") company_id: string,
  ): Promise<Product | null> {
    const product=await Product.findOne({ where: { company_id } });
    console.log(product)
    return product;
    // return product;
  }
}
```

the console.log() does print out the expected object but when i return I am getting

```
Type 'Product | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product | null'.
```

any idea what might be the reason?

Comment: Change your return type from `Promise<Product | null>` to `Promise<Product | undefined>` in your resolver.

Comment: well that worked but! if there is no record is returned i get "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.companyProducts"

Comment: This is because you are using this decorator `@Query(() => Product)` which suggests that a "Product" will be returned, I have limited experience with type-graphql but you could try making all fields nullable since (based on my assumptions) the fields `name` and `company_id` are not nullable.

Comment: Also it may be worth changing the query decorator from `@Query(() => Product)` to `@Query(() => Product | null)` if the above solution didn't work and then `return product;` to `return product || null;`

Comment: Unfortunately, both didnt work!

Comment: Were there any errors that was returned by changing the decorator return type or was it the same as before?

Comment: it was same as before

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your query nullable by `@Query(() => Product, { nullable: true })`.
2. Change your query method return type signature to `Promise<Product | undefined>` or return null when product is undefined.